# auctex inconsistent behavior: tex vs latex

Tags: auctex

I have a fresh install of miktex+emacs+auctex on my windows 10 computer.
Emacs shows a Latex icon which does pdflatex when my file1.tex is loaded and it shows a tex icon which does pdftex when my file2.tex is loaded. Why?

Both files are in latex (so I get errors with my second file.) Both files start with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
```

EDIT: This is even weirder: Now auctex started recognizing file2.tex is latex. Don't know why. (The only thing I can think of is that I opened it once with emacs, rather than loading it into emacs.)

Comment: local variables block? (usually at the end of the file)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, so I suspect the answer is no. "usually at the end of the file" -- you mean my tex files? There are no special or unusual commands there.

Comment: What is this difference of "opened it once with emacs, rather than loading it into emacs"?

Comment: I don't know which icon you are talking about, because I am using GNU/Linux, but remember that the icon issue can also be completely unrelated to AUCTEX. What is the default editor with which your TeX files get opened? Because as far as I have seen GNU Emacs never provides any "icons" in the file explorer. It just has various `major`/`minor` `mode`s with which it initiates. I have faced a different problem though which is described in the next comment because of char-limit. It might be of interest to you.

Comment: Files which didn't start with `\documentclass` command used to get opened with TeX-mode instead of LaTeX-mode. I had to change it with `M-x latex-mode`. So even if I just had `\def\somerandcmd{def}` at the beginning and after it the regular `\documentclass`, AUCTEX used to think that this is a TeX document which was weird. Did your `file2.tex` (I know not now, but) **at any point of time** had such definitions before `\documentclass`?

Comment: I meant check your file hasn't got a block like this specifying tex not latex https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html (that example is setting master file, but you can set any emacs variables in such a block)

Answer (score 1):

Niranjan and David Carlisle are right: Any text before `\documentclass` and any command starting with `%%%` within the file may cause auctex to open the tex file in the Tex-mode. Removing them and reloading the tex file into Emacs will open it in the Latex-mode.